# Triggering useEffect on previous stack screen React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react native project which shows a UserNavigator page consisting of two tabs, one to show active data and the second to show inactive data, all the data can be clicked to navigate to UserDetails page

The problem is when I tried to update the inactive data to active and then go back to the previous screen which is UserNavigator the data on UserNavigator will not be updated since useEffect is not triggered to fetch updated data

Tab Nav page named UserNavigator

```
export default function DataList() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Active" component={ActiveData} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Inactive" component={InactiveData} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

useEffect on Active and Inactive page

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
              await getUserData();
            } catch (err) {
              Alert.alert("", err?.response?.data?.message || err?.message);
            }
            setLoading(false);
          })();
      }, []);
```

function on UserDetails to set user status to active then go back to list

```
const onSetActive = async () => {
        setModalVisible(!modalVisible)
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            const body = {
              _id: item._id,  
              status: "Active",
            }
            const response = await axiosInstance.patch(`/UserData/update`, body)
            await getUserData()
            Alert.alert(
                "Success",
                "User has been set to active!",
                [
                  {
                    text: "OK",
                    onPress: () => navigation.navigate("UserNavigator") 
                  }
                ]
              );
        }
        catch (err) {
            Alert.alert("", err?.response?.data?.message || err?.message);
        }
        setLoading(false)
      }
```

I've been trying to use useIsFocused on Active and Inactive Tab

```
Top Import
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";

const isFocused = useIsFocused();
React.useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
              await getUserData();
            } catch (err) {
              Alert.alert("", err?.response?.data?.message || err?.message);
            }
            setLoading(false);
          })();
      }, [isFocused]);
```

But when I tried to navigate between tabs it will rerender the data even when there isn't any change to the data and it will take more time to navigate and wait for data to be fetched

Navigation.replace won't do since I navigate to UserNavigator page from Main Page if I do that when I press the back button from UserDetails it will go back to Main Page instead of UserNavigator

Is there any alternative solution to my problem? I've been thinking to pass props when navigating to UserNavigator after updating data to trigger useEffect but I don't know how

Comment: Try making `isFocused` a state, then it'll trigger the effect when it's in the dependency array. You can also first try removing the dependency array altogether (remove not put an empty array) to run the effect on each re-render, and see if it's running and  behaving the way you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your reducer engine to achieve it, you can change the variable on any page on the app and subscribe it in any page using `useEffect` like this example:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import store from '../store';

const Page = () => {
   const {isFocused} = store.getState().updateReducer;

   useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            try {
              await getUserData();
            } catch (err) {
              Alert.alert("", err?.response?.data?.message || err?.message);
            }
            setLoading(false);
          })();
   }, [isFocused]);
   return (<View></View>

}

export default Page;
```

Comment: I just learned how to use reducer from your answer, thanks now my code is working fine